# google spreedsheet script stopped working with the property object

Tags: google-apps-script

I found a script half a year ago, which unloads data from Google tables into trello. I use it constantly.

Today, it stopped working with the "data warehouse error" error.
The script swears to work with the properties of the script:

```
function checkControlValues(requireList, requireBoard) {
  var col = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Настройка трелло").getRange("B3:B6").getValues();

  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();

  var appKey = col[0][0].toString().trim();
  if(appKey == "") {
    return "App Key not found";
  }  
  scriptProperties.setProperty("appKey", appKey);
```

Specifically on the line "scriptProperties.setProperty (" appKey ", appKey);"
An error occurs even if you write
  scriptProperties.setProperty ("appKey", "123123");

```
Here is the log of the script:
[17-03-24 15: 35: 21: 837 EAT] Running ...
[17-03-24 15: 35: 21: 846 EAT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet () [0 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 21: 942 EAT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName ([Thrallo Setting]) [0.095 sec.]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 22: 005 EAT] Sheet.getRange ([B3: B6]) [0.063 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 22: 061 EAT] Range.getValues ​​() [0,055 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 22: 143 EAT] PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties () [0.08 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 22: 144 EAT] PropertiesService.getScriptProperties () [0 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 22: 145 EAT] PropertiesService.getUserProperties () [0 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 25: 913 EAT] Properties.setProperty ([appKey, XXXXXXXX]) [3,768 seconds]
[17-03-24 15: 35: 25: 924 EAT] Can not complete the completion in 4,069 seconds. Data warehouse error (line 268, export evaluation file for programming in a trello)
```

I will add that the script stopped working immediately in the heap of google tables, where it was used earlier.

What to do?

I will add that the error appears even on the copied code from the Google documentation (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)

Each line on storing properties produces the same error

```
// Set a property in each of the three property stores.
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();

scriptProperties.setProperty('SERVER_URL', 'http://www.example.com/');
userProperties.setProperty('DISPLAY_UNITS', 'metric');
documentProperties.setProperty('SOURCE_DATA_ID', '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
To save data in bulk, pass a map of key-value pairs to Properties.setProperties(properties). Each key-value pair of the object in the parameter is stored as a separate property:

// Set multiple script properties in one call.
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
scriptProperties.setProperties({
  'cow': 'moo',
  'sheep': 'baa',
  'chicken': 'cluck'
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue! Due to this, my entire script stoped working

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me. Changing PropertiesService.getScriptProperties with PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties has worked in my case.